# Can’t seem to SSH from an iPhone to Mac

Tags: macos, mac, ssh, iphone

I’ve tried using several iPhone apps to connect to my Mac (a 2012 Retina MacBook Pro running OS X El Capitan) via SSH, but it never seems to work.

I have remote login turned on and know my Mac’s IP address, and I’ve even been successful in connecting to it over SSH from other computers, so I don’t think it's a permissions problem or anything like that. I’m telling the iPhone apps to connect to the admin account (and I’m giving the correct password), and I’m using port 22, which all of the apps seem to suggest.

Are there any other reasons why SSH possibly couldn’t be working. It’s telling me that it can't connect to the given server, not that it can't find the server?

Comment: @JakeGould I've got both the phone and the computer connected to the same wifi network, so I suppose I'm doing it over that.

Comment: Are you using a `192.168.xx.xx` IP or something else? No need to give the full address, just your last comment doesn't quite answer Jake's question

Comment: @SimonSheehan I tried using both the numerical ip address and the name-of-mac.local one. The first one it wasn't able to connect to and the second one it wasn't able to recognize by name.

Comment: Was the IP local? Like 192.168.xx.xx?

Comment: @SimonSheehan the IP didnt begin with 192.168 - it began with 10.0.

Comment: I'm wondering if the iphone is using the data connection. Have you tried connecting to your computers IP with the iPhones DATA turned off, and WiFi on? You can find your IP address through the terminal using `ifconfig |grep inet`

Comment: @SimonSheehan wait, so how should I find my IP address — do I use the one it lists in the Sharing category in System Preferences, the one listed by ifconfig |grep inet (which lists a few other IP-like addresses - not sure which is the actual one), or the one I can find by going online and searching for what my "public IP" is (it came out as yet another number)?

Comment: See here: http://i.stack.imgur.com/erWdg.png. This will be your local IP. To find the outside IP (which will probably require router firewall changes to access), you can literally type "What is my IP" into google and it will display your outside IP address.

Comment: @SimonSheehan alright thanks I'll try it out (leaving home now, so I might comment other questions later)